# Address in the DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want the address to be a mandatory field at the time of user and bakery registration.

My address fields are like this, but I am in doubt whether to put FALSE or leave without NULL and BLANK.

**Class User**

```
endereco = models.OneToOneField(
        Endereco, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='user',
        null=True, blank=True
)
```

**Class Padaria**

```
endereco = models.OneToOneField(
        Endereco, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='padaria',
        null=True, blank=True
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` and `blank` defaults to `False`.

You can leave the `blank` attribute (which defaults to `False`) to make the field mandatory in forms and serializers ([if you are using ModelSerializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)) etc.

You can also leave the `null` attribute if you would like to have **always** a one-to-one relation to the object (affects also existing rows in DB). Otherwise, you can set it to `True` if it is not mandatory. This does not affect the blank attribute at the time of creation and editing.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look here and let you know